# Scala: inherited interface member initialization

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, interface, overriding

I have the following code, partly in Java, partly in Scala:

Java:

```
public interface ISubject {
  public void a()
  //...
}

public class CSubject implements ISubject {
  public void a() { /*...*/ }
  public void b() { /*...*/ }
  //...
}

public abstract class AbstractTest {
  ISubject subject;
  //...

  public CSubject generateParticularSubject() {
    return new CSubject();
  }
}
```

Scala:

```
object Test extends AbstractTest {

  override val subject: CSubject = generateParticularSubject() /*1*/

  subject.b() /*2*/
}
```

The issue is: if the line marked '1' is as it is in the code above, the compiler complains that `overriding variable subject in class AbstractTest of type ISubject; value subject has incompatible type`. If I remove the type annotaion `: CSubject` in line '1' and the keywords `override val`, that error disappears but another one appears at line '2': `value b is not a member of ISubject`.

I understand what these errors say and the way the compiler thinks getting these problems. What I do not understand, is how to get the behavior same as in Java, where implementing an interface member of a class, it is possible to initialize it with any kind of class that implements the interface. What is the way to do this in Scala?

**UPDATE:**  Is it truth that it is impossible to realize such a construct in Scala? The reason why I want to do that is because `AbstractTest` contains methods that deal with `ISubject` side of the subject and the child classes who should override `subject` and define it as a narrower class instance, must implement methods specific to that class. At the same time I want `AbstractTest` to keep handling all that regards `subject` and can be handled while it is treated through it's interface `ISubject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java field `subject` is mutable, therefore it cannot be overridden in Scala using a `val`. Also, being assignable, it wouldn't be safe to vary it co-variantly.

You can fix your code by making `subject` an abstract method. That can be overridden covariantly with a `val`, as you are doing in your Scala code.

```
 abstract class AbstractTest {
   public abstract ISubject subject();

   //...

   public CSubject generateParticularSubject() {
     return new CSubject();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve in your `Test` object. If you simply need to work with the result of `generateParticularSubject()` method as an instance of `CSubject`, just use a different name for the variable, i.e.

```
object Test extends AbstractTest {
  subj = generateParticularSubject()
  subj.b()
}
```

> What I do not understand, is how to get the behavior same as in Java, where implementing an interface member of a class, it is possible to initialize it with any kind of class that implements the interface.

What you are referring to here is called "covariant return types" and is indeed supported in Java since version 5 (whereby a method overridden in a subclass is allowed to return a narrower type). However what you are trying to do in Scala code has nothing to with covariant return types, instead you are trying to override a member field of a base class which is really not a good idea. The field is declared as having type ISubject in the base class and should remain so. That is why you can write:

```
object Test extends AbstractTest {
  subject = generateParticularSubject()
  // ...
}
```

but can only then call methods defined in ISubject (as that is the static type of subject, regardless of type returned by generateParticularSubject())

Comment: Answering your question, I can say that what I am trying to acheive - is to put some core processing of `subject` into the `AbstractTest` class. But the children of that class must be able to initialize it to a narrower class instance and define more methods to work with it, that also suit for that particular child class. At the same time, the core methods defined in `AbstarctTest` class should still be able to fulfill their mission treating `subject` as a broader `ISubject`.

Comment: As far as I understand, in Java variables do not get overidden, rather they get shadowed.

Comment: AbstractTest class is aware of type CSubject - that follows from declaration of generateParticularSubject() method - so why not declare `AbstractTest.subject` as CSubject, not ISubject? And secondly, as you correctly say, member fields in Java get overshadowed rathen than overridden and if you want to go that route then `AbstractTest.subject` should really be declared with private visibility and `Test` should have its own `private val subject` of narrower type.

Comment: see the update in the question. What is defined as `ISubject` at first, may become `CSubject`, `CMySubject`, `CTheirSubject` and so on in multiple child classes of AbstractTest. Still, the methods from AbstractTest should be able to handle all these as if they were ISubject-s. Maybe that is an architectural flaw?

Comment: Saw your update to the question. If you want AbstractClass to deal purlely with ISubject I believe you should declare return type of  AbstractClass.generateParticularSubject() as ISubject as well otherwise you are violating your own self-imposed separation of concerns. And then I think you should use overshadowing not overriding, just as you would have to do if both AbstractTest and Test were written in Java.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two options.

The simple one:

```
object Test extends AbstractTest {

  val csubject: CSubject = generateParticularSubject() 
  override val subject = csubject

  csubject.b() 
}
```

The nicer one, especially when you have various places where you want to access subject as an instance of CSubject:

give the AbstractTest a type parameter T which extends ISubject, make subject of type T and in Test bind that parameter to CSubject.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is not possible in either Scala *or* Java. Python or Ruby would let you do it, of course, and they would be wrong (but, then again, they don't check what you are doing at all).

The problem is this, assuming you could do what you want:

```
class DSubject extends ISubject
Test.subject = new DSubject
```

You cannot disallow that assignment because `Test` implements `AbstractTest`, and `AbstractTest` has a public field. To disable assignment would violate `AbstractTest`'s contract.

On your `Test` object, any access to a `CSubject` member would result in error, because `subject` now contains a `DSubject`.

Try something else, such as aggregation instead of inheritance, or a proxy class.